# Bidirectional Hibernate query produces 1+ N queries when using JoinColumns

Tags: hibernate, many-to-one, bidirectional

Parent entity has Annotation as follows:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "a")
private Set<Child> b;
```

Child entity has annotation as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "col_A")
private Parent a;
```

When executing a join FETCH query for Parent via the repository like:

```
@Query("select a " +
            "from Parent a " +           
            "left join FETCH a.b " +
            "where a.prop = <some_value> ")
```

The query works as expected executing one big join that returns A and its children. However if we change the annotation of the Child as follows the query starts executing 1+N:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
           @JoinColumn(name = "COL_A", referencedColumnName = "COL_A"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "COL_B", referencedColumnName = "COL_B")
    })
    private Parent a;
```

The COL_A is the primary key of Parent while COL_B is a non-key column that is used as a partition